# How Graph API handles concurrent uploads?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using MS Graph SDK to download, edit and upload Word documents from/to the cloud.

In another question, I got suggestion to use [`if-match`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) to avoid overwrite anyone else's changes. I looked at the documentation and they didn't specify when **overwrites** will happen?

1. Upload will fail only if there are conflict changes?
2. If no, is there any mechanism to merge non-conflict changes?

I'm running my program in multithread context and there are big chances that one document could be edited by many users at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`If-Match` is definitely what you're after. If you provide the header with a valid etag or ctag, the request will only complete successfully if the current state of the item has a matching etag (or ctag depending on which was provided). If the values do not match a `412 Precondition Failed` response will be returned.

The choice of whether to provide the etag or the ctag in the header is contingent on how sensitive you want to be. The etag covers ALL changes to the file wile the ctag covers only content changes. So if you provided the etag in the `If-Match` header and someone renamed the file your request would fail. On the other hand, if you provided the ctag it would only fail if the actual file contents were changed.

Now merging is a whole different topic, and unfortunately for you it's one that you'll need to write. OneDrive is not in the business of understanding the semantics of all the various file types, and therefore does not know what is a conflicting change, and what is an non-conflicting change. By extension it also does not have any idea how to merge non-conflicting changes for you. If you do end up getting a precondition failure resulting from a change in the service you'll need to download the updated file and perform the merge yourself.

Comment: In my case, I will edit the document after download. So When uploading "values will not match all the time". Does that mean, I will get `402 error` all the time? If not, Graph Api is using a mechanism to track changes so?

Comment: So when you download the document you'll want to keep note of the ETag or CTag headers in the response. Those are what you'd provide when you try and push your updated document back into OneDrive. As long as no one else has modified the document the ETag/CTag you provide should match the current state in OneDrive, and the request should succeed.

Comment: What Will happen When two simultaneous update requests with same etag occur at the same time?

Comment: One will succeed, the other will fail. There will be no way to predict which will be which.